# $\rm SU(3)$ interferometry with qutrits

Tags: quantum-information, interferometry

It is well known that a two-mode interferometer can be described in terms of $\rm SU(2)$ group [Smerzi](https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.5164). I wonder if something similar exists for three-mode interferometer and qutrit states. Not only exists, but also experimentally achievable.